# Could not search when special character is in the string using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search value from table using `Like` keyword and while I am putting special character with text its not showing any result. Here is my query:

```
$name="Henna*/"
$sname='%'.$name.'%'; 
$sql="select * from cn_user_login name like '".$sname."' order by login_id desc";
```

I am providing my table below:

cn_user_login:

```
login_id       name                  status

 1             Heena Mohanty           1

 2            Heena raj                1

 3            Heena@                   1

 4            Heena*                   1
```

Here no search result is coming. Here I need no matter if any special character is there if it will match up to some/all letter the result should come.

Comment: can you please confirm if you are searching for the word "Henna" or "Henna*"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. Remove special characters

```
$name="Henna*/";
$sname = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $name);

$sql="select * from cn_user_login where name like '%".$sname."%' order by login_id desc";
```

Comment: same string can be with different special character.How does this will fetch appropriate result?

Comment: $sname will return as Henna ... thus like %Henna%' ... if you think there are more special characters then widen up the coverage of the regex

Comment: then this will return both Heena@,Heena*. he need to fetch only Heena*.

Comment: correct because it was not stated in the OP that he only wants "Henna*"

Comment: name might have the string with special charcter also.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: see my table if i have input like this `Heena*/`,it should search all name related to Heena .

Comment: yup.. so my question is did you try my answer?

Comment: yes coming but if I have only `$name="Henna"` this `Heena* ` from table should not be there.

Comment: if you are looking for Henna then there is no match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145686/discussion-between-satya-and-mastashufu).

Answer (score 0):

try to replace using the regular expectation

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $name);
```

or

```
 $name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $name);
```

if 
you know the character then use str_replace() function

```
$name = str_replace("your character", '', $name);
```

Comment: when I write my answer then your answer is "addslashes()" function and you edited your answer during i write my answer

Comment: Nope not mine...was from lalith

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use prepared statements from [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

You can just write:

```
$sql = 'select * from cn_user_login name like :param_name order by login_id desc';
$paramName = '%'.$name.'%';

$db = new PDO('dsn_string', 'user', 'password');
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute([':param_name' => $paramName]);
$result = $stm->fetchAll();
```